# Blender Eevee reflection plane gives warped reflection

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection, lightprobe

I want my ground to have a nice reflection, but the reflection plane is acting very strangely (See photo below). What's also weird is that the reflection plane works for most of the scene. When I add the plane I can click around the timeline and it seems like it is work, but when I play the animation through from start to finish the reflection breaks 2/3 through.

I've tried to solve it a few ways, which don't work:Restarting Blender; Downloading latest version of Blender; Deleting plane and creating a new one.

[image: reflectionwokring]

[image: reflectionbroken]

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with my material. I had an image sequence that was input into a normal map. For some reason a few frames of my image sequence were empty (it looked like a missing image) which would through off my normal map and give a weird reflection.

Specifically the problem came because my image sequence started at frame 31 and went to frame 220. The offset was set to 31 so and it ended up adding frames that I never had.